# react native always white screen

Tags: javascript, ios, react-native

I have tried modifying the index.ios.js as follows

```
/**
 * Sample React Native App
 * https://github.com/facebook/react-native
 * @flow
 */

import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { TabNavigator } from 'react-native-tabbar-navigator';

import {
  AppRegistry,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View
} from 'react-native';

export default class PMNative extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text style={styles.welcome}>
          Welcome to React Native!
        </Text>
        <Text style={styles.instructions}>
          To get started, edit index.ios.js
        </Text>
        <Text style={styles.instructions}>
          Press Cmd+R to reload,{'\n'}
          Cmd+D or shake for dev menu
        </Text>

        <TabNavigator>
          <TabNavigator.Item
                selected={this.state.selectedTab === 'home'}
                title="Home"
                renderIcon={() => <Image source={...} />}
                renderSelectedIcon={() => <Image source={...} />}
                badgeText="1"
                onPress={() => this.setState({ selectedTab: 'home' })}>
            {homeView}
          </TabNavigator.Item>
      <TabNavigator.Item
            selected={this.state.selectedTab === 'profile'}
                title="Profile"
                renderIcon={() => <Image source={...} />}
                renderSelectedIcon={() => <Image source={...} />}
                renderBadge={() => <CustomBadgeView />}
                onPress={() => this.setState({ selectedTab: 'profile' })}>
                {profileView}
      </TabNavigator.Item>
     </TabNavigator>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
...
```

But when ti comes to execution , it comes always a white screen . Would you please tell me what to trouble shoot ? (Given processes of all other applications using 8081 is killed )

[image: /Users/larrylo/Dropbox/螢幕截圖/Screenshot 2017-08-23 17.57.52.png]

Updates:

for prolonged idle use, it shows the following after npm start :

[image]

[image]

Comment: any error message?

Comment: Even though I run this dummy project , the white screen still occurs in iOS simulator. Does installing yarn matters the app deployment? 

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html#content

Comment: I'm not sure about yarn (I use npm), but I guess that won't be the problem

Comment: It says could not connect to development server.

Comment: Do you get any errors in the React Packager?

Comment: I have got these error , mentioned in the edited post

Comment: Inside your `package.json`, go up to `scripts` object, what is the value of `start` property?

Comment: no start :   missing script: start

Comment: Bundling `index.ios.js`  [development, non-minified, hmr disabled]  ░░░░░░░░░░░░
░░░░  0.0% (0/1)


stucks and no percentage too.

Comment: Sometimes , org.reactjs.native.example.AwesomeProject: 1485 
generates different number, what is that mean ?

Comment: For the start script add `"start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start"` to your `package.json` under `"scripts": {}`

Comment: How to resolve  the issue that "Loading dependency graph..." and hangs forever ?

Comment: Start script added but still red screen

Comment: try `react-native run-ios` instead of `node index.ios.js` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you to **remove** `node_module` then install it again with `npm install` and also the library used like :

1. remove `node_module`.
2. run `npm install`.
3. install library, base on your case install `react-native-tabbar-navigator`.
4. and try again to build your project with `react-native run-ios`.

i hope my answer can help you.

Comment: At project directory level or at the root level ?